# Parsing n number of UIImage, resultant images getting disordered

Tags: ios, iphone

I am parsing `n` images using `NSUrl` delegates. But I'm not getting the results in the same order.

How can i make it in the same order of request send?

Comment: what do u mean by disorderd? if you post your code it will be helpful

Comment: you'd better add an index property to each image. as the processing time of each image isn't the same, the return order won't be your request send order

Comment: if i send request to load 5 images 1,2,3,4,5 the response may be 1,2,4,3,5 which which is not in the proper order of request

Comment: If you show us how you're using these images (updating UI? updating model or some persistent store? etc.) we can probably offer more concrete advice. Perhaps share a little source.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running these concurrently (i.e. just initiating a whole bunch of `NSURLConnection` requests), this behavior is not at all surprising because while you may initiate them in a particular order, you have no assurances that they'll necessarily finish in that same order. You could address this by initiating these requests serially (i.e. don't start the next request until the prior one finishes), but I'd discourage you from doing that as you'll pay a significant performance penalty. It is much better to refactor your code to handle the fact that they may complete in a non-sequential fashion, rather than placing an artificial constraint that they must finish in a particular order.

So, it's best to employ a mechanism that supports concurrency, but let's you constrain the degree of concurrency (e.g. namely an operation queue). It's not too hard to wrap your `NSURLConnection` requests in individual `NSOperation` subclass objects, but rather than reinventing the wheel, you might want to consider using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), which does a lot of this for you.